# Send multiple arrays and a string using json from ajax to php and receiving them on php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

These are the two arrays which are sent from ajax call to php

```
var mycol=new Array(); 
var mycolval=new Array();
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (var i = 1; i < inputs.length; i++)
            {
                if($("#"+inputs[i].id).val().length>0)
                    {   
                        flag=true;
                        mycol=inputs[i].id;
                        mycolval=$("#"+inputs[i].id).val();


                    }

            }
```

And this is the string

```
var string = $('#search_input').val();
```

I have tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work.
Please help me come up with solution.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "anding.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(mycol:mycol,mycolval:mycolval,string:string),
    success: function(response){}

   });
```

Comment: Why does it not work? What behaviour are you expecting that you don't see? Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code syntax is wrong

```
    data: JSON.stringify(mycol:mycol,mycolval:mycolval,string:string),
```

should be

```
    data: JSON.stringify({mycol:mycol,mycolval:mycolval,string:string}),
```

You might want also want to specify the content type since you're sending JSON

```
contentType: 'application/json',
```

then you can access you data

```
$postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$mycol = $postdata['mycol'];
```

though I am skeptical you actually want to send json but rather url encoded key value pairs so you can access them via `$_POST['mycol']` etc, if so use

```
        data: {mycol:mycol,mycolval:mycolval,string:string},
```

instead.

Also

```
$("#"+inputs[i].id).val()
```

could be simplified into

```
inputs[i].value
```

Comment: How do i access stringify data in php?

Comment: mycol and mycolval are not key value pair.

Comment: @roshan what is that suppose to mean?

Comment: What am i supposed to write instead of ("php://input").

Comment: @roshan that **is** what you suppose to write.